# Google reCAPTCHA V.2 working in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, recaptcha

I am using google reCAPTCHA V.2 in my website, which is running on a localhost in a MAMP server. 
I am doing all the widget integration correctly (both on frontEnd and server side), the proof is that the widget displays correctly on firefox 38.0.1 and that the validation works smoothly
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw97z.jpg
but it displays strangely on chrome
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I1m7.jpg

---

Needless to say, I am doing everything that needs to be done. Again, the proof is that it is working in firefox, but not in chrome...
Without going into detail, in HTML the page looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>reCAPTCHA demo</title>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>
 </head
 <body>
  <form id='reCaptcha' action='myValidationScript.php' method='POST'>
   <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="myKey">
   </div>
   <input type='submit'>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem is not on the server, the code I use in PHP to do the validation looks something like this (again, without going into detail).

```
<?php
 if(isset($formFields['g-recaptcha-response']))
 {$captcha=$formFields['g-recaptcha-response'];}
 $secretCaptchaKey='mySecretKey';
 $response=file_get_contents(
   "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretCaptchaKey&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );
 $response = json_decode($response, true);
 if($response["success"]==true){echo('yay!!')}
 else{echo('nay')}
 ?>
```

The closest answer I've read in the web is from google's FAQ where they discuss the "no_checkbox" issue saying that my client does not have the necessary resources to load the widget and that it falls back to an alternative challenge. But the example they put there (an image with text) is far from the ugly texts I am getting in chrome...

Again, please understand there is no server problem with this, the proof is that it works on firefox...
For information, I had the exact same issue in the past and I solved it by upgrading the browser. Now I have it again in chrome...
any ideas?

Comment: My bad I thought I was searching rails questions only

Comment: No, I am not using any framework at all. the website is written in php... I forgot to mention that my chrome version is 43.0.2357.65 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue here: reCAPTCHA working flawless in Firefox (51.0.1) and displaying the message "invalid domain for site key" in Chromium (55.0.2883.87).

A workaround was to disable the "Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions" checkbox in the reCAPTCHA configuration for my domain which made reCAPTCHA work in Chrome.

Of course, this is not a sustainable solution. Upon further investigation I found out the problem was caused by the German "Umlaut" characters in my domain name. To solve it, I just needed to add the Punycode of my domain to the reCAPTCHA config.